# chartjs Asp.net MVC Remote Data

Tags: asp.net, chart.js

I am trying to user chartjs.org in my application but have no idea, how i can populate related JSON data in controller. 
I need to populate json data as below:

```
var barData = {
                        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                            },
                            {
                                fillColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.5)",
                                strokeColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.8)",
                                highlightFill: "rgba(26,179,148,0.75)",
                                highlightStroke: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                            }
                        ]
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at this library: [Chart.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chart.Mvc)